# How to Automatically Calcuate Interest and add it to each account_id (rows) with SQL and VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I've a table with the column 'Balance' which stores the latest balance of each Customers Account (Account_id). Now I want to add interest over their yearly balance automatically and the interest should be added at their new balance after completing each one year. How can I do that using VB.Net (Visual Studio 2008) and Sql Server (Express edition)?

The table name is Deposit. The columns are like this:

**Trans_id**  **Acc_id**  **Trans_date**  **Amount**  **Balance**

Comment: Need a bit more information here. Like what is the interest rate? What type of interest are you calculating? Why are you storing the Balance? This should be calculated on demand by the sum of transactions.

Comment: Hi, this is the requirement. 
A customer deposits $50 each week. He is bounded to deposit in every week. Now, we'll have to pay him 6% interest after the year. Not on the total amount deposited after the Year. The interest should be calculated partially for every deposit. E.G If some one deposit $50 on first week it will get 6% yearly interest for 1 Year. The next premium ($50 - fixed) will get the interest for (365-7) days, the third premium will get interest for (365-14) days and so on.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to calculate interest in real time? Otherwise you are giving somebody 6% on their deposit for the entire year and they might take it out the next day. This is why I said you shouldn't store the balance but calculate it as needed. Again, what type of interest is this. Is it compounded or simple? Do you seriously get 6% interest every day? If so please tell me what bank this is because I want to put my money there. You are going to need to provide ddl and sample here if you really want some help. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for. I had to add a column to the account table, and I assumed there is a client table with "birth date".

```
declare @customer table(
  [acc_id]    [int] identity(1, 1)
  , [name]    [sysname]
  , [created] [datetime] default dateadd(year, -1, current_timestamp));
insert into @customer
        ([name])
values      (N'joe'),
        (N'sally');
--
declare @account table (
  [trans_id]         [int] identity(1, 1)
  , [acc_id]         [int]
  , [trans_date]     [datetime] default current_timestamp
  , [amount balance] [money]
  , [interest_paid]  [datetime] null);
insert into @account
        ([acc_id],[amount balance])
values      (1,N'25.00'),
        (2,N'50.00');
--
declare @interest [float] = 0.03;
update @account
set    [amount balance] = [amount balance] + ( [amount balance] * @interest )
   , [interest_paid] = current_timestamp
from   @account as [account]
   join @customer as [customer]
     on [customer].[acc_id] = [account].[acc_id]
where  ( datediff(day
              , [interest_paid]
              , current_timestamp) >= 365
      or [interest_paid] is null )
   and datediff(day
                , [customer].[created]
                , current_timestamp) >= 365;
--
select * from   @account as [account]
   join @customer as [customer]
     on [customer].[acc_id] = [account].[acc_id];
--
-- this should not update as the [interest_paid] date is less than one year old
update @account
set    [amount balance] = [amount balance] + ( [amount balance] * @interest )
   , [interest_paid] = current_timestamp
from   @account as [account]
   join @customer as [customer]
     on [customer].[acc_id] = [account].[acc_id]
where  ( datediff(day
              , [interest_paid]
              , current_timestamp) >= 365
      or [interest_paid] is null )
   and datediff(day
                , [customer].[created]
                , current_timestamp) >= 365;
--
select *
from   @account as [account]
       join @customer as [customer]
         on [customer].[acc_id] = [account].[acc_id];
--
declare @future [datetime] = dateadd(year
          , 1
          , current_timestamp);
--
-- this SHOULD update as the [interest_paid] date is a year old based on the future date
update @account
set    [amount balance] = [amount balance] + ( [amount balance] * @interest )
       , [interest_paid] = @future
from   @account as [account]
       join @customer as [customer]
         on [customer].[acc_id] = [account].[acc_id]
where  ( datediff(day
                  , [interest_paid]
                  , @future) >= 365
          or [interest_paid] is null )
       and datediff(day
                    , [customer].[created]
                    , @future) >= 365;
--
select *
from   @account as [account]
       join @customer as [customer]
         on [customer].[acc_id] = [account].[acc_id];
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am new in the project. How do I apply the above queries in my VB.Net project? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry Tanmay, I can help you with sql, but not vb.net!